# module.exports is undefined when adding a class method

Tags: node.js, vue.js, storybook

I'm trying to set up a custom Vue plugin, and external class to use with Storybook. In my storybook `config.js` I have :

```
const addParameters = require('@storybook/vue').addParameters;
const configure = require('@storybook/vue').configure
const Vue = require('vue').default;
const Vuex = require('vuex');
Vue.use(Vuex);
const myClass = require('../myClass.js')

function loadStories(){...}
addParameters({...})
configure(loadStories, module)
```

in `myClass.js`

```
class myClass {
   constructor(){
     this.myVar = 6
   }
}
module.exports = myClass
```

This works fine.

The problem occurs when I add any class methods, I get the error `Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Example

```
class myClass {
   constructor(){
     this.myVar = 6
   }
   getVar(){ return this.myVar }
}
module.exports = myClass
```

I've read that this error can be caused by mixing `import` and `module.exports` but as far as I can tell I'm not doing that. I'm also confused why I *don't* the error until I add a class method. Also, I use this class elsewhere in the proper app just fine using `module.exports` and `require`.

Any ideas what I should look into next?

Comment: Have you tried `export default myClass` instead of `module.exports = myClass`?

Comment: Do you have circular dependences (Each module import each other)?

Comment: @tony19 `export default myClass` works, but I use `module.exports` and `require` in the proper app (this is in Storybook). `export default` fails in the proper app. I'm currently looking into making that not break.

Answer (score 0):

try these

1. `module.exports =  new myClass`
2. mixin - it should look like so

   `module.exports = () => new class newClass extends myClass{
      constructor(){
           super();
   }}`